# Write Error: bad address on writing encrypted data to wrapper filesystem

Tags: encryption, linux-kernel, cryptography, filesystems, kernel

I am implementing a simple caeser cipher on [WrapFS](http://wrapfs.filesystems.org/) to store encrypted data and decrypt while reading. For that purpose I made minor changes to `wrapfs_read() and wrapfs_write()` functions provided in the source code to encrypt and decypt the data. My decryption is working fine, but due to my encryption code I am getting an error on write as follows `bash: echo: write error: bad address`. Any help regarding handling it would be really appreciated.

```
void caeser_encrypt(char __user *encrypted, size_t count)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<(unsigned int)count;i++)
        encrypted[i]=encrypted[i]+3;
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s",encrypted);
    return;
}

static ssize_t wrapfs_write(struct file *file, const char __user *buf,
                size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
    int err = 0;
    struct file *lower_file;
    struct dentry *dentry = file->f_path.dentry;
    char *encrypted = NULL;

    lower_file = wrapfs_lower_file(file);

/*Added by me*/
    encrypted=kmalloc(sizeof(buf),GFP_USER);
    memcpy(encrypted,buf,count);
    printk(KERN_INFO "%d %d",(int)sizeof(buf), (int)count);
    caeser_encrypt(encrypted,count);
    err = vfs_write(lower_file, encrypted, count, ppos);
/*Added by me*/

    //err = vfs_write(lower_file, buf, count, ppos);
    /* update our inode times+sizes upon a successful lower write */
    if (err >= 0) {
        fsstack_copy_inode_size(dentry->d_inode,
                    lower_file->f_path.dentry->d_inode);
        fsstack_copy_attr_times(dentry->d_inode,
                    lower_file->f_path.dentry->d_inode);
    }

/*Added by me*/
    kfree(encrypted);
    return err;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that "const char __user *buf" is user space address and vfs_write expects user space address and you are passing kernel space address to it. Also you cannot directly copy user space address to kernel space address. You can try using copy_from_user and copy_to_user functions. I hope you are aware that caeser cipher is insecure.

Comment: yeah I am totally aware how insecure caeser cipher is that too hard coded one like my, I just gave it here to make it simpler for everyone's understanding.

Comment: I am allocating memory as `encrypted=kmalloc(sizeof(buf),GFP_USER);`, so wont that be in user space because of the `GFP_USER` flag ?

Comment: I think you cannot use user space pointer directly in kernel space. User space memory is paged and kernel have linear memory access. You can use this [approach](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-3) or [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-kernel-memory-access/).